# Regex em CPF com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, regex, laravel-eloquent

O sistema em que estou fazendo manutenção possui CPFs cadastrados de duas formas, com e sem pontuação, devido a um início de desenvolvimento ruim que não impôs um padrão. O problema é que o CPF não pode se repetir, e quando o usuário digita um CPF sem pontuação, se ele já estiver gravado com pontuação, vai indicar que é um novo CPF.

Acredito que eu deveria usar o regex para fazer a comparação dos dois, mas não sei como aplicar à consulta.
Segue abaixo a consulta realizada:

```
$customer = Customer::where('cpf', $valor)->first();
```

Comment: Não seria melhor adequadar todos os registros no padrão correto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maior solução seria normalizar todos os valores da coluna sem formatação. A forma provisória é tratar os valores da comparação da mesma forma ou seja removendo a formatação.

Pode escrever uma consulta no MySQL com `replace()`

```
SELECT replace(replace('123.456.789-10', '.', ''), '-', '')
```

A solução completa deve ser algo como:

```
$valor = str_replace(array('.', '-'), '', $valor);
$customer = Customer::where("REPLACE(REPLACE(cpf, '.', ''),'-', '')", $valor)->first();
```

Comment: `SELECT X_REG_REPLACE('123.456.789-10', '[^0-9]', '');`, não tenho MySQL aqui, se quiser testar.

Comment: Concordo, mas a empresa não está me permitindo normalizar o banco, pois esses dados fazem referência a um outro sistema interno deles, para eu normalizar teria que normalizar no outro sistema, o que é extremamente burocrático. Vou testar essa busca aqui e te falo rray

Comment: Vou ver isso também Guilherme

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert O MySQL não tem função pronta para fazer replace baseado em regex só busca mesmo. O mariadb tem [regexp_replace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/)

Comment: @IsaiasLima Se a consulta ficar lenta e se for viável crie uma coluna nova `cpf_limpo` que armazena o cpf sem formatação então nas pesquisas sempre use ela (para recuperar o cpf compativel com os outros sistemas). Não esqueça de criar um índice único.

Comment: @rray o MySQL é o PHP dos SGBS. Um lixo :/

Answer (score 3):

Em PHP você pode tentar o replace do RegEx dessa forma:

```
$cpf = '12345678968';
$cpf_maskered = preg_replace('/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/','$1.$2.$3-$4', $cpf);
echo $cpf_maskered;
```

Caso o CPF já contenha pontos e traços, ele ficará da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer com php puro:

```
$valor = str_replace(".", "", $valor);
$valor = str_replace("-", "", $valor);
$customer = Customer::where('cpf', $valor)->first();
```

Tirei o exemplo de http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

Vê se funciona.

Comment: O pior é quando o CPF está gravado com pontuação e recebe um valor sem pontuação para comparar (já que não estão permitindo que eu altere a validação do campo, não sei porque, já que resolveria tudo), nesse caso não funcionaria com o str_replace